# PHP PDO $row inside php code not running

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a problem , i am storing a message on my database with $row[name] The text in my database is

```
 Helloo $row['name'] how are you 

$txt[1] is "Helloo $row['name'] how are you "
```

This is the code i tryed the first echo works, but the seccond is not working

```
<?php
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE trimis='0'"); 
$check->execute();
$checkdb = $check -> fetchAll();
foreach($checkdb as $row){

    echo $row['name']; // THIS WORKS

$check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id='1'"); 
$check->execute();
$checkdb2 = $check -> fetchAll();
foreach($checkdb2 as $txt){
    echo $txt[1]."<BR>"; // THIS DOESEN'T
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Add `$<your_connection>->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to catch errors.

Comment: Can you show your code for INSERT?

Comment: i already told you my content it's unnecasary to post the insert method, it's not secured or stripslashes or anything like that, pure text

Comment: @JohnnyValaha if you have `$row['name']` as a string literal in your database then you need to address your insert statement, not the select.

Comment: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($checkdb2, TRUE).'</pre>';` should help you out

Comment: Also, does the `settings` table actually have two columns or more?

Comment: What column from `settings` are you trying to access? Why not refer to it by name?

Answer (score 0):

You should select the specific fields from your table when you write your query,
Because using wildcard `SELECT *` + accessing the rows by index like `$txt[1]` is the recipe for bugs:

```
$check1 = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM appointments WHERE trimis='0'"); 
$check1->execute();
while($rows1 = $check1->fetch()){
    echo $row['name'];
    $check2 = $db->prepare("SELECT custom_text FROM settings WHERE id='1'"); 
    $check2->execute();
    while($rows2 = $check2->fetch()){
        echo $rows2['custom_text']."<BR>"; 
    }
}
```